# I think you guys should turn off the script that deletes single-use tags

Tags: discussion, tags

I don't really use this site much, but I happened to have a gander through your [untagged](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) tag, and wow are there a lot of questions there! It looks like the script that deletes single-use tags has been doing a real number on your site.

[Arqade has requested that it be turned off](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5379/50246), and I think you guys should do the same, since this site is like Arqade in a lot of ways - in particular, you have a really long tail of infrequently-played games, and it's totally reasonable for you to have a lot of tags that only get used less frequently than once in six months.

Answer (score 7):

Single use tags will not be deleted [if someone has given it a tag wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127700/do-not-expire-single-use-tags-that-have-a-tag-wiki). That's the fix here. We no longer disable the deletion script, since it has been updated to ignore single-use tags with tag wikis. So, if this community wants to clean up its [untagged](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) questions, all it needs to do is write a couple of lines in the tag wikis.

Comment: I see. Will the deletion script be turned back on at sites where it is turned off?